# Почему сразу вызывается деструктор после срабатывания конструктора преобразования?

Tags: c++

Всем, добрый день. Пытаюсь разобраться с конструкторами и деструкторами в с++.
Ситуация следующая:

Есть класс Sea:

```
 int ID = 0;
class Sea
{
 private:
char* sea_name;
int max_depth;
double square;
int id;

 public:

int GetID()
{
    return this->id;
}
void SetSeaName(const char* p)
{
    if (strlen(p) != strlen(this->sea_name) || this->sea_name == nullptr)
    {
        delete[] this->sea_name;
        this->sea_name = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
    }
    strcpy(this->sea_name, p);
}


//Конструктор 1
Sea(const char* arr, int d, double s) :max_depth(d), square(s)
{
    this->sea_name = new char[strlen(arr) + 1];
    strcpy(this->sea_name, arr);
    cout << "constructor is called!" << endl;
    this->id = ID++;


}
//Конструктор 2
Sea(int d, double s) :Sea("cde", d, s)
{


}
//Деструктор
~Sea()
{
    delete[] sea_name;
    this->sea_name = nullptr;
    cout <<"Destructor called for object with ID= " << this->id << endl;
    cout << "Destructor" << endl;
}
//Конструктор по умолчанию
Sea()
{
    cout << "default constructor is worked" << endl;
    this->sea_name = new char[4];
    strcpy(this->sea_name, "abc");
    this->max_depth = 1000;
    this->square = 100000;
    this->id = ID++;
}

//Конструктор копирования
Sea(const  Sea&  param) :max_depth(param.max_depth), square(param.square)
{
    this->sea_name = new char[strlen(param.sea_name) + 1];
    strcpy(this->sea_name, param.sea_name);
    cout << "Copy Constructor is worked!" << endl;
    this->id = ID++;



}
//Конструктор преобразования
 Sea(const char* p)
{
    this->sea_name= new char[strlen(p) + 1];
    cout << "Convert Constructor is worked!" << endl;
    this->id = ID++;
};

 //Конструктор преобразования explicit
explicit Sea(int p)
 {
     this->sea_name = new char[p];
 };

 };
```

В main создаю экземпляры данного класса:

```
int main()
{

   setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

{
    cout << "-----------------1---------------" << endl;
    Sea s1;
    cout << "ID= " << s1.GetID() << endl;
    cout << "-----------------2---------------" << endl;
    Sea s2("aaaa", 1000, 2000.5);
    cout << "ID= " << s2.GetID() << endl;
    cout << "-----------------3---------------" << endl;
    Sea s3(1000, 200.5);
    cout << "ID= " << s3.GetID() << endl;


    //Конструктор преобразования
    cout << "-----------------3---------------" << endl;
     s3 = "kfg";
     cout << "ID= " << s3.GetID() << endl;

     //Конструктор преобразования explicit
    /* s3 = 'a';*/
     cout << "-----------------4---------------" << endl;
     //Конструктор копирования
     Sea s4 = s1;
     cout << "ID= " << s4.GetID() << endl;
    cout << "-----------------GlobalFunction ---------------" << endl;
    GlobalFunction(s2);

    cout << "-----------------GlobalFunction ---------------" << endl;

}
Sea* s4 = new Sea();
s4->~Sea();
GlobalFunction(s4);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Каждому объекту в конструкторе присваиваю значение id по которому на выводе  могу видеть что за объект и когда для него вызывается деструктор. Значение id для конкретного объекта получаю из глобального ID - который  инкриментирую при вызове любого из конструкторов.
В итоге получаю такую картину:
Как здесь можно видеть, при работе с объектом s3 - при использовании конструктора преобразования, после его работы - для объекта сразу вызывается деструктор(для объекта с ID 3),но:

- Во-первых, я не могу понять почему это так? Я знаю, что для конструктора перемещения ВРОДЕ БЫ - удаляется оригинал после "перемещения" - т.е происходит копирования, а потом удаление оригинала, но почему вызывается диструктор этого же объекта, для которого вызывается конструктор преобразования - я понять не могу.
- Во вторых, на приведенном мной скриншоте - не полный вывод, т.к программа далее падает с ошибкой при попытке вызвать деструктор для s3 (оно и понятно - т.к деструктор для него уже был вызван), но не понятно следующее:
  для того что бы избежать этой ошибки я попытался в самом деструкторе, который в моем примере просто освобождает память выделенную под массив - "занулить" указатель с помощью nullptr

  ```
   ~Sea()
   {

  delete[] sea_name;
  this->sea_name = nullptr;
  cout <<"Destructor called for object with ID= " << this->id << endl;
  cout << "Destructor" << endl;
   }
  ```

  т.е при первом вызове деструктора для текущего объекта - он освободит память и занулит указатель на массив, что бы при повторном вызове деструктора - ошибки не возникало (т.е по факту, деструктор все равно отработает и отработает
- `delete[] sea_name;`, но т.к `sea_name` уже будет nullptr, то ничем это не грозит). Но она возникает. В чем моя ошибка в понимании ситуации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кроме того, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос,  вы могли бы получать очень много замечаний от меня, начиная с того, что вы держите глобальный обьект для класса, а не статический в классе и на каждой строке...

Comment: Можно подробнее? Лучше в виде ответа. Не совсем Вас понял.

Comment: в виде ответа нельзя, поскольку это не будет ответом на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- У вас в программе *два* объекта с `id=3`. Один - это временный объект, который создается конструктором преобразования из `"kfg"`. Второй - это объект `s3`, у которого изначально был `id=2`, но потом вы перетерли его `id` и заменили его на `3` при помощи оператора присваивания в строке `s3 = "kfg";`.

  Временный объект с `id=3` сразу удаляется, как и должно быть. Именно это и есть ваш вызов деструктора с `id=3`. А объект `s3`, у которого теперь тоже `id=3`, продолжает жить.

  Если вы хотите следить за уникальными объектами при помощи таких `id`, то вам нужно руками написать оператор присваивания и позаботиться о том, чтобы он не копировал `id`. Когда мне необходим ID с такой функциональностью, я пишу специальный класс `PersistentId` с пустым конструктором копирования и оператором присваивания. Тогда мне не нужно ни о чем беспокоиться в классах, использующих такой ID.
- У вас в программе нарушено Правило Трех - не написан оператор присваивания. Это приведет к ошибкам при малейших попытках использовании присваивания.
- О какой "попытке вызвать деструктор для s3" вы ведете речь мне не ясно - ничего подобного в коде нет. В любом случае, повторный вызов деструктора для такого нетривиального объекта - это неопределенное поведение и пытаться заниматься "реанимацией" этого неопределенного поведения какими-то дополнительными проверками - пустая трата времени.

  А падения кода ваши - это в первую очередь последствие нарушения Правила Трех.
- > Я знаю, что для конструктора перемещения ВРОДЕ БЫ - удаляется оригинал после "перемещения"

  Ничего подобного. Конструктор перемещения делает только то, что в нем написано. У вашего класса вообще нет никакого конструктора перемещения - вы его не написали.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Свою ошибку вроде бы понял. Насчет конструктора перемещения - правильно, нет и не планировалось.

Comment: Кроме того вы вызываете деструктор для s4, а он вызывается повторно  при завершении программы